# QueryDSL Spring JPA Hibernate IllegalArgumentException Parameter value not matching type

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to configure QueryDSL + Spring JPA + Hibernate. The QueryDSL 'Q' query classes for my domain objects get generated using Maven POM configurations. I have a 'Person' object which has a String attribute 'username'. I want a person returned with username = "jon". When I run a simple application by assigning username as "jon" I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [person.username = jon] was not matching type [java.lang.String]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.registerParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:360)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.setParameter(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.setParameter(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.bind(CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.invokeBinding(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:134)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:395)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:486)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 49 more
```

Can someone assist? Relevant class + files are below.

My Person class:

```
package com.motodoc.hub.domain;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Entity
@Table(name="persons")
public class Person implements UserDetails {

@Id
@Column(name="PRS_ID")
private int id;

@Column(name="PRS_USERNAME")
private String username;

@Column(name="PRS_PASSWORD")
private String password;

@Column(name="PRS_FIRST_NAME")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="PRS_MIDDLE_NAME")
private String middleName;

@Column(name="PRS_LAST_NAME")
private String lastName;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES", joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "USR_PRS_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "RLE_ID") })
private Set<SecurityRole> roles;

@Transient
private final String PERMISSION_PREFIX = "ROLE_PERM_";

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Set<GrantedAuthorityImpl> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthorityImpl>();
    for (SecurityRole role : roles) {
        for (SecurityPermission permission : role.getPermissions()) {
            GrantedAuthorityImpl authority = new GrantedAuthorityImpl(PERMISSION_PREFIX + permission.getPermission());
            authorities.add(authority);
        }
    }
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}


public String getPERMISSION_PREFIX() {
    return PERMISSION_PREFIX;
}

public Set<SecurityRole> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<SecurityRole> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

}
```

The QueryDSL generate QPerson class:

```
package com.motodoc.hub.domain;

import static com.mysema.query.types.PathMetadataFactory.*;

import com.mysema.query.types.path.*;

import com.mysema.query.types.PathMetadata;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.mysema.query.types.Path;
import com.mysema.query.types.path.PathInits;


/**
 * QPerson is a Querydsl query type for Person
 */
@Generated("com.mysema.query.codegen.EntitySerializer")
public class QPerson extends EntityPathBase<Person> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1472547386;

    public static final QPerson person = new QPerson("person");

    public final StringPath firstName = createString("firstName");

    public final NumberPath<Integer> id = createNumber("id", Integer.class);

    public final StringPath lastName = createString("lastName");

    public final StringPath middleName = createString("middleName");

    public final StringPath password = createString("password");

    public final SetPath<SecurityRole, QSecurityRole> roles = this.<SecurityRole, QSecurityRole>createSet("roles", SecurityRole.class, QSecurityRole.class, PathInits.DIRECT2);

    public final StringPath username = createString("username");

    public QPerson(String variable) {
        super(Person.class, forVariable(variable));
    }

    public QPerson(Path<? extends Person> path) {
        super(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    }

    public QPerson(PathMetadata<?> metadata) {
        super(Person.class, metadata);
    }

}
```

Service class:

```
package com.motodoc.hub.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.motodoc.hub.domain.Person;
import com.motodoc.hub.domain.QPerson;
import com.motodoc.hub.repository.IPersonDao;
import com.mysema.query.types.Predicate;

public class SecurityUserServiceImpl implements ISecurityUserService {

    @Autowired
    private IPersonDao personDao;

    @Override
    public Person findByUsername(String username) {

        QPerson query = QPerson.person;
        Predicate predicate = query.username.eq(username);
        return personDao.findByUsername(predicate);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> findAll() {
        return personDao.findAll();
    }

}
```

Repository class:

```
package com.motodoc.hub.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor;

import com.motodoc.hub.domain.Person;
import com.mysema.query.types.Predicate;

public interface IPersonDao extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Person> {

    public Person findByUsername(Predicate predicate);

}
```

POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.motodoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.motodoc</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hub</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <spring.core.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.core.version>
    <spring.data.jpa.version>1.7.2.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>

    <cglib.version>2.2</cglib.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.6.10</aspectj.version>

    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.16</mysql.connector.version>
    <hibernate.entitymanager.version>3.6.3.Final</hibernate.entitymanager.version>
    <hibernate.jpa-api.version>2.0-cr-1</hibernate.jpa-api.version>
    <c3p0.version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>

    <querydsl.version>3.2.4</querydsl.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.14</log4j.version>

    <javax.servlet-api.version>3.0.1</javax.servlet-api.version>
    <javax.jstl-taglibs.version>1.1.2</javax.jstl-taglibs.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.3</jackson.version>

    <!-- Testing -->
    <mockito.version>1.8.5</mockito.version>
    <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <tomcat7.maven.plugin.version>2.0</tomcat7.maven.plugin.version>
    <jetty.maven.plugin.version>8.1.5.v20120716</jetty.maven.plugin.version>
    <maven.copy.plugin.version>0.2.3</maven.copy.plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>2.3.2</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <maven.apt.plugin.version>1.1.3</maven.apt.plugin.version>
</properties>

  <dependencies>
  <!-- Spring Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- A seamless aspect-oriented extension to the Java programming language -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Cglib is a powerful, high performance and quality Code Generation Library, 
    It is used to extend JAVA classes and implements interfaces at runtime.  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library (JSTL) encapsulates, as simple tags, core 
    functionality common to many JSP applications. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.jstl-taglibs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.jstl-taglibs.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Data Mapper package is a high-performance data binding package built 
        on Jackson JSON processor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson is a high-performance JSON processor (parser, generator) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The Simple Logging Facade for Java or (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade or abstraction 
    for various logging frameworks, e.g. java.util.logging, log4j and logback, allowing the end 
    user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database pooling -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--  MySQL Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate and JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.jpa-api.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.entitymanager.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- QueryDSL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <!-- <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>  -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <!-- <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>  -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
      <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
      <!-- <scope>provided</scope>  -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Javax Servlet. This needs to be included for runtime only! -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>hub</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <!-- Tomcat 7 plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat7.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>8080</port>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Jetty 8 plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/spring-thymeleaf-tutorial</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>

                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/generated</outputDirectory>
                        <!--  <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor> -->
                        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.hibernate.HibernateAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        <options>
              <querydsl.entityAccessors>true</querydsl.entityAccessors>
            </options>  
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


        <!-- The Resources Plugin handles the copying of project resources to the 
            output directory. @see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-meta-inf</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/META-INF</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>

  <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>bootstrap</id>
            <repositories>

                <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
                <repository>
                    <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
                    <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
                    <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>full-bootstrap</id>
            <repositories>

                <!-- For main Spring releases -->
                <repository>
                    <id>org.springframework.maven.release</id>
                    <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
                    <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>

                <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
                <repository>
                    <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
                    <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
                    <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>

                <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
                <repository>
                    <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
                    <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
                    <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>

                <!-- JBoss repository -->
                <repository>
                    <id>jboss</id>
                    <name>JBoss repository</name>
                    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
                </repository>

            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing predicate, just pass the username to your repository method

```
findByUsername(String username);
```

When you have `findBySomething` , Spring will look for a property called `something` in your entity, and obviously the passed parameter have to be matched with the type of `something`.

If you really want to have it with your predicate, you can pass the predicate to built in methods, such as `findOne()`, `findAll()` or `count()`. So your service might look like

```
 @Override
 public Person findByUsername(String username) {
      QPerson query = QPerson.person;
      Predicate predicate = query.username.eq(username);
      return personDao.findOne(predicate);
 }
```

Comment: I'm trying to configure QueryDSL with my application. This is a simple test I'm carrying out to see if I've configured everything correctly because the queries will get complex, hence the use of Predicate etc.

Comment: Please see my edited answer, how to deal with QueryDSL.

Comment: Aahh, I was using the findBySomething method when I should have been using the findOne method in conjunction with the predicate Thank you for your help.